# Searching CoreData using regex and special characters

Tags: ios, regex, core-data

So I'm trying to search through core data. Let's say my `CoreData` has two fields which are `NSString` (we'll call them foo & bar).  The user gives an indication of which field to search and the search string.  Right now I'm using this code:

```
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ matches[c] %@)", field, @"%@"];

// Double-escape that slash
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@.*", partialString];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format, pattern];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Field is passed in as either "foo" or "bar".  Partial string is the search string. If bar contains "Grand Poobah", I want it to match when "Poo" is the query string (but not when it's "oobah", that's why I have the \b in the regex).

But the issue I have is if someone gives a query of "Poo(" it crashes because it gets interpreted as part of the `regex`.

Is the best route to simply escape all the special characters in partialString before building pattern?  Or is there some other way I should be building the predicate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you should escape all special characters in the search string, and there is an
easy method to do so:

```
NSString *escapedString = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:partialString];
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@.*", escapedString];
```

But you should not use `stringWithFormat` to build a predicate format string (as in your 
first line). Simply continue

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K MATCHES[c] %@", field, pattern];
```

Note that `%K` the predicate format must be used for a *key path* substitution.

Comment: Thanks. Using the stringWithFormat didn't feel right, but when I tried to condense it, it kept crashing on me. But I was missing the %K at that point.

Comment: bro this code is matching only the first characters what about the rest can u please help me out... i need to search a character from a string